# .NET Projects: Where do I put .resx files?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, design-patterns

Where do I put .resx files? Sometimes I see these files under Properties folder. Is there any design guideline about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a WinForms app, the .resx file associated ot a class (form, user-control,...) is stored side-by-side with the source code (e.g. C#) file. In addition, a global .resx file is created in the properties to let you store global stuff such as messages, pictures,...

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you are doing.

For example a web Application they go in App_GlobalResources or App_LocalResources folder.

For other projects I would create a Resource folder and put them there.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click your project in VS solution explorer you should have an option "Create folder"  this will then have a list of folder you can create.  App_GlobalResources and App_LocalResources is another.

For project wide strings and resources add the contents to the App_Global forlder.  for form specific resources add the content to the App_Local folder instead.

[Have a look here for more information](http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm)

Comment: My project is for Smart Device: a library and a Windows Form App.